# Arranging layouts is not proper when using BorderLayoutContainer of gxt3

Tags: java, gwt, layout, gxt

I am facing the different issue, whenever i am trying to resize the contents of my window it is not getting resized. I also tried the Resize Handler way.

As we can see there is two components SnapshotChooserView and RunLogGrid and i have made it collapsible.
So, that when i make the SnapshotChooserView collapsed, then all the space should be occupied by the RunLogGrid and when i collape the RunLogGrid all the other space should be occupied by the SnapshotChooserView.

Can anyone help to figure this out.

```
public class RunView implements IsWidget {

// Client factory
private ClientFactory iClientFactory;

// Main Container
private BorderLayoutContainer borderLayoutContainer;

// Components
private SnapshotChooserView snapshotChooserView;

// Components
private RunLogGrid runLogGrid;

ContentPanel north;

ContentPanel south;

ResizeHandler handler1;

ResizeHandler handler2;

// ---- CONSTRUCTORS ----

public RunView() {
}

public RunView(ClientFactory aClientFactory) {

    iClientFactory = aClientFactory;


    borderLayoutContainer = new BorderLayoutContainer();
    borderLayoutContainer.setBorders(true);

    snapshotChooserView = iClientFactory.getSnapshotChooserView();
    runLogGrid = new RunLogGrid(iClientFactory);

    final double SnapshotChooserHeight = 500;
    final int RunLogGridHeight = 350;

    handler1 = new ResizeHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
            north.setWidth(event.getWidth());
            north.setHeight(event.getHeight());
        }
    };

    handler2 = new ResizeHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
            south.setWidth(event.getWidth());
            south.setHeight(event.getHeight());
        }
    };

    north = new ContentPanel();
    north.setHeadingText("Run Details");
    north.add(snapshotChooserView.asWidget());
    north.setCollapsible(true);
    north.setResize(true);
    north.addResizeHandler(handler1);
   // north.forceLayout();

    south = new ContentPanel();
    south.setHeadingText("Run Log Info");
    south.add(runLogGrid.asWidget());
    south.setCollapsible(true);
    south.setResize(true);
    south.addResizeHandler(handler2);
   // south.forceLayout();

    BorderLayoutData northData = new BorderLayoutData(SnapshotChooserHeight);
    northData.setMargins(new Margins(2, 2, 2, 2));
    //northData.setCollapsible(true);
    //northData.setSplit(true);
    //northData.setCollapsed(true);
    //northData.setCollapseMini(true);


    BorderLayoutData southData = new BorderLayoutData(RunLogGridHeight);
    southData.setMargins(new Margins(2, 2, 2, 2));
    //southData.setCollapsible(true);
    //southData.setMinSize(RunLogGridHeight);
    //southData.setMaxSize(850);
    //southData.setSplit(true);
    //southData.setCollapseMini(true);
```

//     borderLayoutContainer.addResizeHandler(handler1);
   //     borderLayoutContainer.addResizeHandler(handler2);

```
    borderLayoutContainer.setNorthWidget(north, northData);
    borderLayoutContainer.setSouthWidget(south, southData);

}

/*
 * @see RunLogGrid::TriggerGridReload
 */
public void triggerRunGridRefresh() {      
    runLogGrid.triggerGridReload();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.IsWidget#asWidget()
 */
@Override
public Widget asWidget() {
    return borderLayoutContainer;
}
```

}

Comment: The resizing in GXT will only work, if you start with a [Viewport](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/container/Viewport.html) and then use GXT containers as the parent/ancestors of your BorderLayoutContainers. Did you do that?

Comment: Either viewport, or specify a size directly. Additionally, both GXT layout containers or GWT layout panels can be used as parents, provided they are configured to give a size to their children. GWT's RootLayoutPanel is not sufficient, as it doesn't signal that an initial size is ready.